# Select Option not Work only Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I need to call a function when I click on a select option with a class choice. Everything works fine on Firefox, Internet Explorer and Opera but not on Google Chrome.

Here's the code:

```xml
<fieldset class="suburbSelect">
    <label for="suburbSelect">Provincia</label>
    <select class="suburbSelect">
        <option class="alessandria" value="Piemonte, Alessandria">Alessandria</option>
        <option class="asti" value="Piemonte, Asti">Asti</option>
        <option class="biella" value="Piemonte, Biella">Biella</option>
        <option class="cuneo" value="Piemonte, Cuneo">Cuneo</option>
        <option class="novara" value="Piemonte, Novara">Novara</option>
        <option class="torino" value="Piemonte, Torino">Torino</option>
        <option class="verbania" value="Piemonte, Verbano Cusio Ossola ">Verbano Cusio Ossola</option>
        <option class="vercelli" value="Piemonte, Vercelli">Vercelli</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

```js
jQuery(".alessandria").click(function(){  
    alert(hello!);
});
jQuery(".asti").click(function(){  
    alert($(".asti").attr("class"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/all2aller/KqPCs/2/

I'm using Jquery 1.9.1.

Comment: why you need like that

Comment: little code fix: wrap "hello!" with quotes or it will throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working code and demo:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".suburbSelectElmnt").change(function () {        
        var activeClass = $(".suburbSelectElmnt option:selected").attr('class');
        switch (activeClass) {
           case 'alessandria':
           alert("hello!");
           break;
           case 'asti':
           alert(activeClass);
           break;
       }
   });
});
</script>
<fieldset class="suburbSelect">
    <label for="suburbSelect">Provincia</label>
    <select class="suburbSelectElmnt">
        <option class="alessandria" value="Piemonte, Alessandria">Alessandria</option>
        <option class="asti" value="Piemonte, Asti">Asti</option>
        <option class="biella" value="Piemonte, Biella">Biella</option>
        <option class="cuneo" value="Piemonte, Cuneo">Cuneo</option>
        <option class="novara" value="Piemonte, Novara">Novara</option>
        <option class="torino" value="Piemonte, Torino">Torino</option>
        <option class="verbania" value="Piemonte, Verbano Cusio Ossola ">Verbano Cusio Ossola</option>
        <option class="vercelli" value="Piemonte, Vercelli">Vercelli</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

[Jsfiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/neerajkumarsingh/RLhhJ/)

Comment: hank you very much and very interesting. But I found another way to do what I needed and it seems to work on all browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/KqPCs/30/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a typo here:

```
    alert(hello!);
```

it should be:

```
    alert("hello!");
```

Second, your usage of classes is quite weird in this case.... you got a class for each selected option, which is a bit non-standard way of checking for the value of a select box.

Instead, you can use jQuery's change() and val() functions, like this:

```
$(".suburbSelect").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();

    if (val == "Piemonte, Alessandria") {
        alert("hello!");
    } else if (val == "Piemonte, Asti") {
        alert($(".asti").attr("class"));
    }
});
```

I've updated your jsFiddle accordingly here:

http://jsfiddle.net/KqPCs/5/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning it off and on again? :)

I had exact same problem, and it got fixed when i restarted chrome.